# How to implement a "follows"/has-many relationship with mongoosejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating an app with mongoose and express.I have user and venue models.

I want users to follow venues and view all the venues they are following. I also want to display all users following a venue on the venue's page. A user follows many venues and a venue has many user followers.

What is the best way to implement this relationship with the mongoose ORM? What should my models look like? What about the CRUD following operations?

I have seen [mongoose-relationship](https://github.com/sabymike/mongoose-relationship) but it does not seem very popular. What is the mongoose.js community solution to implementing this "following" database relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the user model/Schema will have an "venuesFollowing" array containing venue._id's.  The venue model/Schema will have a "usersFollowing" array containing user._id's.

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = Mongoose.Schema;
var Venue = require('./venue');

var userSchema = new Schema({
  fullName: {type: String, required: true},
  username: {type: String, required: true},
  email: {type: String, required: true},
  venuesFollowing: [{type: Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId , ref: 'Venue'}],

});

var User = Mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

You can use this user model as a basis to construct your venue model and substituting the venuesFollowing with users following.  You are requiring the Venue model so that it can be referenced in this user model and vice-versa. You will be able to access all of the users following a venue by their ID's and vice-versa for the the users and the venue id's that they follow.